# BOA installation caching does not refresh

Tags: caching

I have recently migrated an existing site into a fresh BOA platform. The problem I am facing is that the cache for the anonymous users is never cleaned, when new content is added. The anonymous user can only see new content by adding ?nocache=1 at the URL. But otherwise cache is not regenerated neither by drush cc all.

Given that this happens when boost is disabled, I conclude that this is an issue with speed booster. I tried all suggested solutions to reduce the TTL to 30seconds or so, but there is no improvment. New content is not even displayed for the devel.domain.com, which is supposed to have TTL of 1 second. So I don't know what to think.

Adding ?noredis=1 helps only occasionally, most of the times it delivers older content as well.

If the anonymous user submits a comment, caching gets suspended, as it should be according the documentation.

Edit: I also noticed that drupal reports

> 1 error has been encountered when purging URLs Array

and nginx gets similar errors

> Blockquote [alert] 52902#0: *65633 stalled cache updating, error:0 while closing request, client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1:8888

I am copying here the headers of a normal request and I would appreciate some directions on how to resolve this issue, which is actually preventing totally all my sites from working. This is a news and forum website, where content needs to be displayed immediately, the latest after a minute or so.

Response Headers

```
Cache-Control public, max-age=0
Connection close
Content-Encoding gzip
Content-Language el
Content-Type text/html; charset=utf-8
Date Thu, 30 Jan 2014 01:09:38 GMT
Expires Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified Thu, 30 Jan 2014 00:58:19 +0000
Server nginx
Transfer-Encoding chunked
Vary Accept-Encoding, Cookie
X-Cookie-Domain .mysite.com
X-Device normal
X-GeoIP-Country-Code DE
X-GeoIP-Country-Name Germany
X-NoCache Cache
X-Server-Name www.mysite.com
X-Speed-Cache EXPIRED
X-Speed-Cache-Key /node/4042
```

Request Headers

```
Accept text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Cache-Control max-age=0
Connection keep-alive
Cookie has_js=1; __utma=1.2022174721.1391038387.1391038387.1391038387.1; __utmb=1.49.10.1391038387; __utmc=1; __utmz=1.1391038387.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __unam=f0418e2-143e0596284-fd42fad-47
Host www.mysite.com
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0
```

Response Headers From Cache

```
Cache-Control public, max-age=0
Connection close
Content-Encoding gzip
Content-Language el
Content-Type text/html; charset=utf-8
Date Thu, 30 Jan 2014 01:09:38 GMT
Expires Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified Thu, 30 Jan 2014 00:58:19 +0000
Server nginx
Transfer-Encoding chunked
Vary Accept-Encoding, Cookie
X-Cookie-Domain .mysite.com
X-Device normal
X-GeoIP-Country-Code DE
X-GeoIP-Country-Name Germany
X-NoCache Cache
X-Server-Name www.mysite.com
X-Speed-Cache EXPIRED
X-Speed-Cache-Key /node/4042
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Please make sure you are using latest BOA stable
2. Make sure you have configured custom Speed Booster TTL properly (INI or code)
3. Note that default is just 10 seconds, so there is no way it can cause such issues
4. Disable Purge+Expire modules, unless you are forcing long TTL
5. Check the docs at: https://omega8.cc/node/108 for working code examples
6. Make sure it is not some other caching layer (Views?) which adds confusion

I hope this helps.